# WebDav server iis unable to configure some of the webdav settings

Tags: iis, webdav, iis-10

I have setup a WebDav Virtual directory on local network with

1. Anonymous authentication.
2. Virtual Directory : All Permissions granted to AppPool
3. Binding added on ip port 80(http://192.168.0.8/localSystemDir/). Able to access the directory over local network.
4. Using Windows 10 with IIS 10.0.18362

**Problem**: I'm unable to configure some of the behaviors(grayed out) under Authoring rule-> WebDav Settings.
I need to configure Property behavior but it is not configurable for me. I need these for connecting to WebDav via REST API

[image]

**Window features enabled :**
[image]

P.S: I'm new to IIS and WebDav and might me missing something obvious!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you explained i reproduce your issue(actually this is not an issue it is default behavior) at my side and found we can not apply some web dev setting to the application or virtual directory. you need to apply the setting at the site level and it will inherit to the sub-application or virtual directory.

the only thing you can do is at virtual directory is apply the authorization rule other than the web dev setting will inherit from the site level.

if you want to do some setting you could use configuration editor:

[image]